# Are `switch` statements generally used wrong?

Tags: java, c++, coding-standards, switch-statement, usage

I see most developers using `switch` statements with `break`s in each and every `case`. Is this usage of `switch` statements inappropriate since a simple set of `if-else` statements would suffice?

Is it OK for me to think that the only reason for you to use a `switch` is because two or more `case`s are related, so you intentionally want some statements to "fall through"?

An example in which I think it's OK to use a `switch` is the case in which you want to update the schema of a database; so if you are updating from version 1 to version 4, you want to make sure the schema goes through versions 2 and 3 first:

```
private void updateDatabase(int oldVersion){
   switch(oldVersion){
      case 1:
         updateToVersion2();
      case 2:
         updateToVersion3();
      case 3:
         updateToVersion4();
   }
}
```

A NOT OK example of a `switch` is where I use it in a video game to move a character based on the button pressed. I would have to `break` each `case` so that when pressing `LEFT` the character doesn't move in all directions:

```
private void onButtonPressed(Button button){
   switch(button){
      case LEFT:
         moveLeft();
         break;
      case RIGHT:
         moveRight();
         break;
      case UP:
         moveUp();
         break;
      case DOWN:
         moveDown();
         break;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Um, you know that C# **requires** a `break` (or other "jump" statement) to end a case, right?

Comment: @RossPatterson My bad. Java, C++, JavaScript and most other languages then.

Comment: The schema transition is a brilliant example of using a switch statement!  Right on!

Comment: What is it about putting a `break` at the end of every `case` that makes it not OK?  Your first example could be done with `if` statements, too.

Comment: I tend to find that I'll use a switch case if I'm going to do more than one else if. For me it's all about readability so I also then go ahead and bury the switch statement in it's own method to ensure it's as clean as possible. There's no huge difference between the two really, I'd say which ever is more readable is what you should be using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No, `switch` statements are not generally used wrong.**

They are mostly used for their intended use: enumerating action alternatives for a smallish set of possible input values. It's more readable then a long if/else chain, compilers can emit very efficient code if the checked values are reasonably contiguous, and it's easier to write error-checking compilers that warn you when you forget an alternative. All this is well and good. (Using `switch` when inheritance and dynamic dispatch would be preferable is a common mistake among beginners who don't understand OOP very well yet, but that is a higher-level issue.)

**However, `switch` is *defined* badly in most languages.**

Since by far the most common use case is to do something different for each case, it's annoying and clutterful having to write `break` after each case that isn't a fall-through. The `switch` statement would work much better if `break` were the default after a `case` body, and you had to order fall-through via an explicit `fallthrough` keyword (unless two `case`s are directly adjacent). That would remove a lot of unnecessary lines, and many, many people wouldn't have made subtle errors by forgetting a `break`.

However, it's definitely too late now to do anything about that; C does it that way, and none of its descendants was brave enough to change anything about it, so for the time being, `switch` will probably stay as it is.

Comment: It's not quite true that no C descendants have switched to explicit fall-through/implicit break. See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/162615/why-dont-languages-use-explicit-fall-through-on-switch-statements

Answer (score 9):

Since `if/else` is similar to a `switch` and often interchangeable, your confusion is understandable.

Some languages, such as Python, don't even have a `switch` statement. Not surprisingly, when you Google for "python switch", [the first result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60208/240613) points to an alternative—a map. Not an `if/else`, but a map.

While you *can* use `if/else` every time instead of a `switch`, you should also understand that your colleagues are not *wrong* when they use a `switch` statement. Either they were simply told by a teacher or a mentor that they should use a `switch` when there are more than two branches, or they simply find it more *elegant* or *readable*, both terms being perfectly subjective.

Your first example, by the way, annoys me a lot. If I were a reviewer of your code, I would immediately flag it, because **it's easy to overlook the lack of `break` statements**, and so it *looks* like if `oldVersion` is `2`, only `updateToVersion3()` will be executed, but not `updateToVersion4()`. Avoid writing code which is prone to errors. For instance, such syntax is forbidden in C# precisely in order to avoid mistakes which are so easily avoidable.

Your second example is a case where **`switch` is perfectly fine**. Although I would use instead either a map (mapping functions—or even lambda expressions, and not their results) or inheritance, I would switch to `switch` statement if I know that my code will be read by beginners who may not understand those two approaches.

If the style guidelines of your code base allow it, your second example may even be written this way:

```
switch (button){
    case LEFT: moveLeft(); break;
    case RIGHT: moveRight(); break;
    case UP: moveUp(); break;
    case DOWN: moveDown(); break;
}
```

or like this:

```
switch (button){
    case LEFT:  moveLeft();  break;
    case RIGHT: moveRight(); break;
    case UP:    moveUp();    break;
    case DOWN:  moveDown();  break;
}
```

making the code shorter and more readable (again, readability is subjective) than an `if/elif/else` variant.

An important aspect [highlighted](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/269996/are-switch-statements-generally-used-wrong/270001?noredirect=1#comment550297_270001) by [J Trana](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/112465/j-trana) is that in this second example, `if/elif/else` may be error prone. I can't easily find a more illustrative example where you can migrate to `switch`, but the following piece of code shows the idea. Are you able to immediately see why the following code will sometimes throw an exception at runtime (imagine it's 6 PM and you've spent three hours inspecting code)?

```
if (!fs.FileExists(fileFullPath)) {
    debug("The file appears to be missing. Check if the location is set in the options.");
}
if (fs.ReadFile(fileFullPath).Contains(textToFind)) {
    found = true;
    debug("The file contains the expected text.");
}
else {
    debug("The text was not found.");
}
```

Here again, in C#, the official style guide will prevent you from writing this error prone piece of code: it would require to add a line break before the second `if`, and the author of the code will immediately see that he wrote `if` instead of `else if`.

That's why, in order to reduce the risk of writing code which doesn't express clearly the intentions of the author and can easily be misread:

- Avoid the missing `break`s in `switch` statements, except in the case where the previous `case` contains no logic:

  ```
  switch (something)
  {
      case 1: // Not having a `break` is fine. The intention of the author is clear.
      case 2:
          hello();
          break;

      case 3:
          world();
          break;
  }
  ```
- Avoid `else if` which may be confused with or, by mistake, replaced by, an `if`, unless the style guidelines are protecting you.
- Use maps and inheritance when appropriate. In *most* cases, maps and inheritance are more appropriate than `if/elif/else` or `switch`. Longer `if/elif/else` or `switch` tend to be a good sign that they should be replaced by a map (often) or an inheritance (rarely) or should be completely refactored (often).

  The record I've seen so far is a `switch` statement containing approximately a thousand `case`s (written by an *expert* proud of his 15 years' professional experience as a *lead developer*).
- Flatten hierarchies when possible. This code:

  ```
  if (n == a) {
      f1();
  }
  else {
      if (n == b) {
          f2();
      }
      else {
          f3();
      }
  }
  ```

  should immediately be refactored to:

  ```
  if (n == a) {
      f1();
  }
  else if (n == b) {
      f2();
  }
  else {
      f3();
  }
  ```

  or:

  ```
  switch (n) {
      case a:  f1(); break;
      case a:  f2(); break;
      default: f3();
  }
  ```
- Beware of insane programmers. This piece of code is equivalent to the one in the previous point, if `a`, `b`, `c` and `n` are numbers (things would be different if those were calls to functions with side effects):

  ```
  if (!(n == a)) {
      if (n - b == 0 && !(n > b)) {
          f2();
      }
  }

  if (!(n == a) && n - b < 0 || b - n < 0) {
      f3();
  }

  if (n != a) {
      // Do nothing.
  }
  else {
      if (!(n > a) && ! (n < a)) {
          f1();
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Speaking of error-prone code, am I the only that's accidentally used an if-if rather than an if-else-if in a chain of ifs and gotten burned by two blocks executing? The "NOT OK" use of cases with breaks (especially in C#) has probably saved me quite a few times because it usually implies mutual exclusion.

Comment: "it's easy to overlook the lack of break statements". The lack of break statements is the whole point; in my opinion it's not a flaw, it's what makes the use of the switch OK in the example.

Comment: @JTrana: great point. I added it to the answer, although I can't find a great example where `if/if/else` can be replaced by a `switch`.

Comment: @YasmaniLlanes: *"The lack of break statements is the whole point"*: yes, I know. The problem is, it makes the code error prone, given that the error can easily be avoided.

Comment: I don't think falling through to the next case is necessarily a bad idea, but what it is is uncommon enough that to do it without an explicit indication that it is intentional is a very bad idea.  There are languages where break is implied at the end of each case unless you use an explicit "fallthrough" statement. In implicit fall-through languages you can use a comment to indicate the intent, but this isn't as good as having a "fallthrough" statement. See also: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/162615/why-dont-languages-use-explicit-fall-through-on-switch-statements

Comment: @Jules: good point. I think it depends on the culture of a particular programmer. Having spent the last 7 years working with C#, I can hardly imagine myself writing fallthrough cases in any language. Other persons with a different background may find it not only acceptable, but even natural.

Answer (score 2):

Some languages ([Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) compiled to JVM, Haskell, Ocaml, etc...) have [pattern matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching) which is superior to `switch` since its deconstruct data structures and bind variables (locally to the matching case).

For example, in Ocaml you might define a simplistic [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) data type (a *sum type* or [tagged union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union)) for expressions as:

```
type expr = 
    Num of int
   | Sum of expr * expr
   | Diff of expr * expr
   | Prod of expr * expr
  (* etc... *)
;;
```

Then you would represent the AST of `2*(3+4)` as

```
   Prod (Num 2, Sum (Num 3, Num 4))
```

and your recursive evaluation function is

```
let rec eval exp = 
  match exp with
   Num x -> x
   | Sum (el,er) -> (eval el) + (eval er)
   | Diff (el,er) -> (eval el) - (eval er)
   | Prod (el,er) -> (eval el) * (eval er)
   (* etc....*)
```

Notice that the matching variables `el` and `er` have their scope limited to each match clause, like lines above starting with `|` (and they are bound by the matching operation)

The compiler generally translates pattern matching into `switch` like constructs (e.g. indexed jumps) and field extractions.

Answer (score 1):

I see what you're saying, but this is ultimately not improper.

If it's just one or two `elses`, an `if-else` change will suffice.  But if it grows to be more than that, I'd say `switch` statements can quickly turn into something that's just cleaner and less of an eyesore to look at.  Or...depending on who you are personally, it could turn it into something that's even messier.

It's strictly cosmetic in the case where you always break out of everything, but saying that it's particularly bad is like saying that between `/*...*/` comments and `//` comments, one is completely better than the other.  If nothing's wrong with long `if-else` chains, then what's wrong with the more trivial `switch` statements?  It's just cosmetic, in cases where this question applies, and you'll find people on each side of the fence on which looks neater.  There is no huge convention over this.

But if something is wrong with `switch` statements where you do break out of everything, as opposed to just using `if-else` chains, then what is there to justify `switch` statements where you don't break out of everything?  Take your first example (which I agree with `Brandon`, it was sharp!):

```
private void updateDatabase(int oldVersion){
    switch(oldVersion){
        case 1:
            updateToVersion2();
        case 2:
            updateToVersion3();
        case 3:
            updateToVersion4();
    }
}
```

Couldn't this just as easily have been written as the following:

```
private void updateDatabase(int oldVersion){
    if (oldVersion > 0 && oldVersion < 4){
        if (oldVersion < 3){
            if (oldVersion < 2){
                updateToVersion2();
            }
            updateToVersion3();
        }
        updateToVersion4();
    }
}
```

Is this better or worse cosmetically?  It's a matter of opinion.  Is this better or worse in terms of performance?  Technically, depending on how the language is compiled, there's probably one extra `int` vs. `int` comparison that's been introduced, but is that really going to cause one microscopic fraction of the performance hit that using a high-level programming language will?  Realistically, you've probably either already made sure that `oldVersion` is more than `0`, or you would need to add a similar check to your function with the `switch` statement.

Some people even think this:

```
switch (true)
{
    case variable1:
        doSomething1();
        break;

    case variable2 && variable3:
        doSomething2();
        break;

    case !variable4 && variabl5:
        doSomething3();
        break;
        .
        .
        .
    default:
        doSomethingElse();
}
```

is ultimately cleaner code than:

```
if (variable1)
{
    doSomething1();
}
else if (variable2 && variable3)
{
    doSomething2();
}
else if (!variable4 && variable5)
{
    doSomething3();
.
.
.
}
else
{
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

(Notice the difference in where the curly braces were placed in the last two snippets; when people do it this way, which is the subject of an ongoing debate in certain languages, it will probably affect their disposition towards the cleanliness of `switch` statements.)

Nothing's wrong with the trivial break-out-of-everything use of `switch` statements, but an experienced programmer should be able to see what it is you hold against them.

Comment: Which language allows non-constant case labels? I don't know of any.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau JS, PHP, etc.

Comment: @Hey: Thanks. It seems to be an unintended usecase as I had to really dig through the documentation to find examples of it.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau unfortunately it's more common "in the trenches" ;)

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I don't specifically remember ever using it myself, though it's probably happened once or twice.  A high-ranking AS3 guy on Stack Exchange brought it up one time, I think on Stack Overflow, and then it's just been something in the back of my mind since.  I tend to think it's cleaner than a long `if-else` chain, especially if you're dealing with fall-through cases, but not if it's a real short one.

Comment: @Hey I'm tagging you for the comment above.